# Regex grab and rewrite string between two other keywords

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some issues with rewriting a string between two "keywords" in a string. Here is the regex pattern in question:

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, "FEW([0-9]{3})", "few clouds at $1.");
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, @"(?s)(?<=[0-9]{2}SM).+0([0-9]{1})0.+?(?=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})", "$2 thousand");
```

Basically I need to get the cloud layers in a METAR, specifically the "FEW070"

```
KLAX 032109Z 26014KT 10SM FEW070 SCT120 BKN220 21/17 A2986 RMK AO2
```

I want it to return a few clouds at 7 thousand, but it's returning few clouds at 070.

I've been using [this program](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) to test the regex expressions and using the above pattern, it returns 7 like it should.

Comment: `modify = Regex.Replace(modify, @"FEW0?(\d)0?\w+", "few clouds at $1 thousand.");` works for me, but I'm not sure if it's what you want. The output ends up being: `KLAX 032109Z 26014KT 10SM few clouds at 7 thousand. SCT120 BKN220 21/17 A2986 RMK AO2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, @"FEW0*(\d+)0", "few clouds at $1,000.");
```

Comment: Just tried, but VS returns an error: "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: try by replacing \d with [0-9] or \\d

Comment: @Spencer, put an `@` in front of the pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

[A simpler regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459127/1711796) will probably be better, but here's what's wrong with yours:

- Neither `(?s)` nor `(?<=...)` are capturing groups, thus you must use `$1` instead of `$2` to get the `7`.
- You replace the string with `"few clouds at 070"`, but then you don't recall the `"few clouds at "` part again. You should put `.+` in brackets and use `$1$2` instead of `$1`.
- You should probably use `.+?` instead of `.+`.

Final code:

```
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, "FEW([0-9]{3})", "few clouds at $1");
modify = Regex.Replace(modify, @"(?s)(?<=[0-9]{2}SM)(.+?)0([0-9]{1})0.+?(?=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})", "$1$2 thousand.");
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/VquKvM).